# sbt: moving boilerplate 'ThisBuild / organization := "com.acme"' to a plugin

Tags: scala, sbt

We have dozens of repos such that our `build.sbt`'s all have what is turning into boilerplate such as this incantation:

`ThisBuild / organization := "com.acme"`

Along with maybe a 100+ lines of similar pre and post ambles.

I can't figure out how to do this bit in a plugin.   I've put it in the AutoPlugin object and the `autoImport`, but that has no effect.   It seems reasonable to change keys in the plugin, but I'm not sure how and could find no examples.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the [`buildSettings`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/api/sbt/AutoPlugin.html#buildSettings:Seq%5Bsbt.Def.Setting%5B_%5D%5D) method. Note however that `ThisBuild` is probably going to be [deprecated](https://eed3si9n.com/simplifying-sbt-with-common-settings/) soon.